# How to make certain properties required but all allowed in an interface or ovject literal type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I want an object type, where some properties are required, but all are allowed.

For example:

```
type a = { b: any }
let c: a = { b: 2 } // works
let d: a = { b: 2, e: 3 } // error
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, one way to do it is you can combine two types together:

```
type Identifier = { id: string };
type SomeOtherData = Record<string, any>;
type DataWithId = Identifier & SomeOtherData; // <= use `&` to combine two types

// Works without any keys except `id`:
const test1: DataWithId = { id: 'test' };

// Works with `id` and more keys:
const test2: DataWithId = { id: 'test', other: 'various other things' };

// Intentionally does not work when `id` is missing:
const test3: DataWithId = { other: 'various other things' };
```

Comment: Tysm, but what is a Record?

Comment: @TheFreeze check out the "advanced types" page of typescript docs

Answer (score 0):

The intersection in [@K48's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56947142/2887218) works, although the conventional solution to this would be to add an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) to the type:

```
interface A { // could also be "type A =" 
  b: any,
  [k: string]: any // index signature
}

let c: A = { b: 2 } // okay
let d: A = { b: 2, e: 3 } // okay
```

I made `A` an interface instead of a type alias but it doesn't matter much (usually the rule I follow is: if something *can* be an `interface` then it *should* be an `interface`; otherwise make it a `type`).

The caveat with index signatures is that properties of known keys (like `b`) must be assignable to the index signature which includes that key.  Since both properties are `any` there, it's fine, but something like this would be an error:

```
interface BadA {
   b: number | string; // error!
// ~ <-- Property 'b' of type 'string | number' 
//       is not assignable to string index type 'number'.  
   [k: string]: number; 
}
```

because according to the string index, the `b` property of `BadA` must be a `number`, while the actual `b` property is `string | number`.  The point here is that the string index doesn't mean "all `string` keys except for `"b"`"; it means "all `string` keys *including* `"b"`".

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IPTeQgewFcAbAE2ThIGcDkAjFAIjAE8AHFdAXiYFgAUMgYAuSiFYBuQcIDaAazHUwUUAHMAumLgTJOPKDIQAHsmrA1IOGCJQIggL6DBJCGHxiemUcgBMyBz1cZAJ5OFYXN2QyT2Rub3oxXwAaZAgxAGYAoLxQ8OcBUEhYRBQAITgydAwZYUTkECIAW0YoZAAfMxV1HLSoKAIoAEJBYIA-ZAAeAFpp5AAFAc4oNmQAcno1kJhkNk515VUQNQ6G5tat0bxhG+RgagaCdzhqc0s4elddukP1O5AjKY9ig1o0WtA1gA6YS1ZAKJTdY5aM7gqB6RwFIA)